Issue with smb share on a linux server connecting from a mac
We are attempting to setup SMB on our linux servers to be connected to from windows, linux and mac clinets but we are running into an issue where the Mac cannot change permissions using chmod. At this point I have attempted to throw the kitchen sink at it and I still cannot get this to work. Is anyone able to tell me what I need, or the problem I am having?
   server string = %h server (Samba Server Version %v)
   netbios name = scrc-working-p1
   server min protocol = SMB2_10
   client max protocol = SMB3
   client min protocol = SMB2_10
   hosts deny = NONE
   security = ads
   unix password sync = yes
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY
   map to guest = Never
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 10000
   ntlm auth = no
   realm = DOMAIN
   obey pam restrictions = no
   machine password timeout = 0
   ea support = yes
   vfs objects = acl_xattr catia fruit streams_xattr
   map acl inherit = yes   
   fruit:aapl = yes
   fruit:metadata = stream
   fruit:resource = file
   fruit:encoding = native
   fruit:copyfile = yes
   fruit:model = MacSamba
   fruit:veto_appledouble = no
   fruit:posix_rename = yes
   fruit:zero_file_id = yes
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
   fruit:nfs_aces = no
   readdir_attr:aapl_rsize = yes
   readdir_attr:aapl_finder_info = yes
   readdir_attr:aapl_max_access = yes
   unix extensions = yes
[staff-digitized]
   comment = Staff share for digitized
   path = /storage/digitized
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   valid users = +"domain\lscrc-dp-staff"
   admin users = +"domain\lscrc-dp-staff"
   create mask = 774
   directory mask = 774
   force create mode = 775
   force directory mode = 755
   oplocks = False
   level2 oplocks = False
   force group = NCSU
   force user = lsmbmount.svc
   fruit:posix_rename = yes
   fruit:veto_appledouble = yes
   fruit:nfs_aces = yes
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = no
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = no
   unix extensions = yes


Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects. Is your Mac UID:GID 0:0? For ancient security reasons NFS remaps 0:0 to nobody:nobody.

what Linux distribution and what specific version of samba server?

rhel 9 and samba 4.20.2. I just noticed I cannot change permissions on another linux client either, so it seems to be something share related not client OS related.

I am not familiar with using samba with security=ads.  I have always used it with security=user and passdb backend = tdbsam and that results in having to do a specific smbpasswd -a <user> for those user accounts defined in /etc/passwd on the Linux samba server.  And then when that user account name syntax matches that account from the connecting client to samba server, if the smbpasswd matches the... windowsNT password on Windows... I assume the same is true on MacOS, then the samba server authenticates that user and allows the connection.  From RHEL-7 to RHEL-8.10 I have never needed more than a basic default smb.conf file which can be as simple as this:
[global]
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No

[scratch]
    comment = scratch
    path = /scratch
    read only = No
    directory mask = 770
    create mask = 660

for SELINUX if it is enforcing on the samba server you need to

setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/scratch(/.*)?"
restorecon -vR /scratch
if the samba share is an NFS mount, then setsebool -P samba_share_nfs on

it is also worthwhile doing service smb status -l and making sure there's no errors.

I have disabled SELINUX to remove that from the mix. Also we are using ads because we want to use SSSD to manage the logins based on our AD accounts.

You have ea support = yes and map acl inherit = yes, which both require that the underlying filesystem should support extended attributes.
What is the filesystem type of your /storage/digitized, and does it support user-settable extended attributes? XFS filesystems apparently always allow them, but other filesystem types might require a user_xattr mount option, or something similar.
To test, make sure the attr RPM package is installed (dnf install attr if it isn't), then run:
getfattr -d -m - /storage/digitized/*

Each Samba-generated file should have at least some extended attributes like security.NTACL, system.posix_acl_access, trusted.SGI_ACL_FILE or user.DOSATTRIB associated with them, with what looks like base64-encoded values.
If Samba cannot create these extended attributes, it cannot support the full set of Mac and Windows permissions interfaces, which might cause problems in operations like chmod through Samba. Even with a basic Unix-style chmod operation, Samba needs to consider the "whole picture" of all types of access control applicable to the file or directory in question, to keep all access control methods consistent.

Thank you for the post, the server and the other rhel client both have attr installed and the unerlying filesystem is xfs. When I use getfattr  on the server I get the extended attributes, but on the rhel client I do not,
security.NTACL=0sBAA```
